# Making username-independent os.rename

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, filepath

I was making a module for my friend, which knows of basically nothing on the coding side of things, so I had a setup.py which will put things from the download folder to the folders the projects need to be in. However, my friend does not know their computer username, so I used
`os.getlogin()`, but when I try to put the variable I assigned the value to into the file paths, it gives multiple errors.

Here is my current code:

```
import os

user = os.getlogin()

os.rename(r"C:\Users\"" + user + "\FILEPATH\FILEPATH\FILENAME", r"C:\Users\"" +
         user +"\FILEPATH\FILEPATH\FILENAME")
```

Comment: "*it gives multiple errors.*"—Any more details?

Comment: @khelwood here: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*********\Desktop\*******\SETUP.py", line 6, in <module>
    user +"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\******")
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\"*******\\Desktop\\***********\\SETUP.py' -> 'C:\\Users\\"*******\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\*******'
>>>

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `r"C:\Users\""` is problematic.

```
>>> path_prefix
'C:\\Users\\"'
```

[From the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

> Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the result; for example, r"\"" is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; r"\" is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw literal cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the literal, not as a line continuation.

You can combine f-strings with raw strings in order to avoid the issue you're encountering:

```
import os

user = os.getlogin()

os.rename(
    fr"C:\Users\{user}\old\path",
    fr"C:\Users\{user}\new\path",
)
```

You could also use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to get the user's home directory:

```
import os

home = os.path.expanduser("~")

os.rename(
    fr"{home}\old\path",
    fr"{home}\new\path",
)
```

Having said that, using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) appears to be a more appropriate way to join paths while avoiding concatenation with the `+` operator and dealing with raw strings and/or backslashes:

```
import os

home = os.path.expanduser("~")

os.rename(
    os.path.join(home, "old", "path"),
    os.path.join(home, "new", "path"),
)
```